# Get all transfers of a token contract from etherscan API with python

Tags: ether, etherscan, python, external-api

I am trying to pull out from etherscan api all token transfer from a particular token contract.

Currently, I can pull data by manually going to etherscan token contract page - for ex cvc coin:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x41e5560054824ea6b0732e656e3ad64e20e94e45
and then on the bottom of the page ' [ Download CSV Export ' allows me to import the CSV in python to get token transfer list and all transfers info:
(Txhash    ,Blockno,   UnixTimestamp   DateTime,   From,   To, Quantity)

However, I would prefer using an api call to get the exact same data but I can't found out which one. It would be something like this one:

url = 'https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs
&fromBlock=0
&toBlock=latest
&address=0x419d0d8bdd9af5e606ae2232ed285aff190e711b
&apikey='+apikey_etherscan
request = requests.get(url)

But this requests yields a dictionnary of transfers like this:(no exploitable info on quantity)

: address': '0x419d0d8bdd9af5e606ae2232ed285aff190e711b',
'topics': ['0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925',
'0x00000000000000000000000020363f72700b58ff49690c5f875b30ad7057001a',
'0x0000000000000000000000008d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819'],
'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e8d4a51000',
'blockNumber': '0x3cdddf',
'timeStamp': '0x595fbcdd',
'gasPrice': '0x12a05f200',
'gasUsed': '0x196992',
'logIndex': '0x25',
'transactionHash': '0x9cdaebf12c1032c648601ffbe9607e876deaac81ed65931a4952113fa353493d',
'transactionIndex': '0x32'}

I am sure there is a better way to do it directly with python without etherscan?
Could someone help?! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, did you succeed ? I have same problem

Comment: Wonder this too!